# Defining and Indexing into a two-dimensional array - C

Tags: c

If I define an array like `static double a[100];` then can I index into it later on like so `a[1][1]`? I thought that if I wanted a two-dimensional array I needed to define it like `static double a[100][100];`

Comment: Why should it be allowed? And why don't you try it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I define an array like static double a[100]; then can I index into
>   it later on like so a[1][1]?

No.. You can't . This is just a single dimensional array a[1][1] will be random access of some memory leading to undefined behavior so will be reported during compile time as an error.

Yes you can have a 2D array `a[100][100]` and access `a[1][1]`

Comment: `a[1][1]` is a compile time error, if a is declared like `static double a[100];`.

Comment: @mch Thanks for it I added it to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, as types don't match. The `a[1][1]` is equivalent to:

```
(*(*(a+1)+1)
```

As your array is defined as `static double a[100];`, second (outer) dereference is simply invalid.

However I believe that you *could* create a pointer, that simulates two-dimensional array within. Here is proof-of-concept, to get an idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    static double a[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        a[i] = i;

    double (*p_a)[10] = (double(*)[10]) a;

    printf("%f\n", a[55]);
    printf("%f\n", p_a[5][5]); // evaluated as 5 * 10 + 5

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if this is fully sanctioned by C Standard and you definitely need to be careful not to go out-of-bounds. Despite that, it seems to reasonable to treat `100` elements one-dimensional array to be *isomorphic* with `10x10` two-dimensional array of the same type. Essentially there are both guaranteed to have the same memory layout. This is due to a fact, that two-dimensional arrays are arranged "by rows" continuously (i.e. first row, second row, ..., last row).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot simply just make a one dimensional array into a two dimensional array. However, you can create an array like `int a[100][100]` and access the values in the array by providing their locations such as `int b = a[x][y]` where x and y are some numbers from 0 to 99.

Comment: _some numbers from 0 to 100_  This is incorrect.  ***100*** would be out of bounds